# Como criar uma variavél que só aumenta igual a um ID em swift 4?

Tags: swift

Preciso criar uma variavél, **idAtual** toda vez que eu for adicionar um novo departamento o ID tem que ser o **idAtual + 1**, más toda vez que eu crio o idAtual no DepartamentoViewController , ele reinicia com o valor que eu declarei, como faço pra fazer esse valor ser constante e apenas crescer ?

Answer (score 2):

Pode parecer complicado, mas é bem simples: Cada vez que voce accessar a properiedade counter do user defaults, adicione 1 ao resultado, salve o novo valor nas preferencias (UserDefaults) do usuario e depois retorne o valor da sua variavel

```
extension UserDefaults {
    static var counter: Int {
        let counter = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "counter") + 1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(counter, forKey: "counter")
        return counter
    }
}
```

---

```
let id1 = UserDefaults.counter  // 1
let id2 = UserDefaults.counter  // 2
let id3 = UserDefaults.counter  // 3


print("id1:", id1, "\nid2:", id2,"\nid3:", id3)
```

> id1: 1
>
> id2: 2
>
> id3: 3

Para resetar as preferencias (UserDefaults) do seu app (incluindo o contador)

```
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uai jovem tu que salvar esse valor, e depois que o app fechar manter ele e isso ?

se for so incrementar e so isso aqui

Declarar

```
var id = 0
```

Incrementar

```
id = id + 1
```

Se quiser salvar pesquise por UserDefaults deve resolver

https://medium.com/@benhur.ott/swift-3-salvando-objetos-em-userdefaults-4920691cd846

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults